# Violation 'setInterval' handler took <N>ms

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

I'm getting `[Violation] 'setInterval' handler took <N>ms` message in browser console.
What does this indicate ?

How can I make below code better to avoid this warning message.

React code is -

```
function PopularBrands() {
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");

    const paginate = () => {
      setSlideIndex((index) => {
        console.log(index);
        if (index === 4) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return index + 1;
        }
      });
    };
    const interval = setInterval(paginate, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return ...

 }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218699/chrome-violation-violation-handler-took-83ms-of-runtime - i.e. it's not fatal in any way.

Comment: As an aside, you can simplify your code with `setSlideIndex((index) => (index - 1) % 4 + 1)`.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid calling setInterval with code that requires processing within the statement itself, always pass in completed values.