# Violation: 'setTimeout' handler took XXms

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-devtools

**Expected behaviour:** When i am on a page for x amount of time, once that time expires when i press back on the window i am redirected to a custom page of my choice, in this case google.

My code works however i noticed in the console i am getting a log that says ***"[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took XXms"***

Why does this happen? Is there another way to write what i am trying to achieve that is more performant perhaps using new Date() ?

```
        let redirect = false;

        const ref = setTimeout(() => {
            redirect = true;
            console.log('history');
        }, 5000);

        addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
            if (redirect) {
                clearTimeout(ref);
                event.preventDefault();

                window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/"
            }
        });
```

Comment: it actually says `XXms`? - that's not very useful

Comment: that was to demonstrate a value, should've probably written it clearer but it does display is correctly eg: 82ms

Comment: oh ... look ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218699/chrome-violation-violation-handler-took-83ms-of-runtime - but thats 83ms ... I wonder if it's relevant for 82ms

Comment: oh i see, hmm it's more so a warning. I wonder if there is a way to make it performant overall. Well there was this 

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/14251/0/datenow-vs-settimeout#latest_results_block

Comment: Your handler couldn't take so long, so this warning is about a different one.

Comment: what if i wanted it to go on for x hours ? Am i better off implementing it another way ?