# JQuery confirmation dialog produces Chrome console '[Violation] Handler took Xms' warning

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I have a click handler that requires confirmation before proceeding:

```
$('.entry').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");
    if (confirmation) {
        //do Ajax 
    }
    return false;
});
```

Adding the confirmation produces a Chrome violation error in the console.
The ms shown is the time it takes the user to click ok/cancel.

Is there a way of preventing this message showing in the console?
Moving the Ajax call into its own function doesn't make a difference.

Comment: [Please create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218699/chrome-violation-violation-handler-took-83ms-of-runtime