# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'jquery')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, es6-modules, pinia

**How to combine jQuery and JavaScript es6 in same file without error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IyX7.jpg)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'jquery') at form.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null(setting '_chart') at custom.js
```

How to clear this errors any solutions below mentioned theme file was used
https://lineone.piniastudio.com/dashboards-cms-analytics.html

```js
window.addEventListener(
    "app:mounted",
  function () {
    // Tab
    new Tab(document.querySelector(".tab-wrapper-community"));
    // member profile option 1 total clubs
    var e2 = {
        colors: [""],
        chart: {
          type: "area",
          stacked: !1,
          height: 120,
          parentHeightOffset: 0,
          toolbar: {
            show: !1,
          },
        },
      },
      t2 = document.querySelector(".overall-club");
    setTimeout(function () {
      (t2._chart = new ApexCharts(t2, e2)), t2._chart.render();
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and when possible, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue so the community can better understand the problem and provide you with better answers. Also, [avoid uploading images of code/errors/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13927534) in your question.

Comment: See here for "[violation]" warning - just means your code is too slow (or using async:false)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824402/2181514

Comment: "reading jquery" means the object *before* jquery is null, eg if you have `var myobject = null; myobject.jquery` - will give *Cannot read properties of null (reading 'jquery')*.  So it's not jquery, but whatever random code that you've not shown us.  Please provide sample code that *demonstates* the issue.  See [mcve].

Comment: how to add code https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m

Comment: This has nothing to do with "combining es6 and jquery" - it has to do with your `form.js`

Comment: ?  locate the code in your IDE, find the *relevant code* only (not the entire .js file), highlight it, ctrl-c to copy... [edit] question, click the `[<>]` button, ctrl-v to paste...

Comment: `t2 = document.querySelector(".overall-club");` - t2 is null

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting '_chart') how to fix that null error

Comment: By not having `t2==null`