Encountered Violation warnings in console repeatedly when tried perform events like scroll, click, or mouseleave
I recently updated Angular from version 11 to 14, along with Angular Material. After the update, whenever I trigger events like click, change, scroll, blur, mouseover, or mouseleave, I receive multiple warnings in Chrome: [Violation] 'click' handler took 361ms.
These warnings are causing my application to slow down, resulting in a poor user experience. Interestingly, the application works perfectly in Firefox without these warnings.

I want to resolve these warnings so my application will run faster.

It seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218699/chrome-violation-violation-handler-took-83ms-of-runtime
