# “Violation readystatechange handler took 760ms” After Updating Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typeerror, magento-1.9, colorbox

After updating [Google Chrome v57.0.2987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history),
our website is getting errors when we open [Collorbox](https://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/):

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

    [Violation] 'readystatechange' handler took 760ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 51ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 43ms
    [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 38ms
```

This only happens sometimes. And when we get these errors, Colorbox does not work for us.

Is there maybe a bug on Google Chrome?

**Edit:**
[Magento](https://magento.com/) merging JavaScript is causing the error. This is what’s not working right. If I don’t merge them, then I don’t get these errors and it’s loading correctly.

```
VM23586:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null  at choose (eval at <anonymous> (0a9e2e3….js:11743), <anonymous>:4:73)  at HTMLImageElement.onclick (letto-moderno-imbottito-prisma.html:1)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined  at HTMLDivElement.onclick (letto-moderno-imbottito-prisma.html:1)
```

Comment: it was working before the last update of chrome, so I guess it must be a colorbox request that is too heavy?

Comment: AKA Synchronous calls are bad.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms/41218580

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Violation Long running JavaScript task took xx ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Chrome is just saying that your code [is blocking the UI too much](https://twitter.com/malyw/status/800421380902645760).

Comment: I had the same problem. On a button click, I was `alerting` the user via a pop up, and the pop up would stay there until the user clicked on 'OK'. I changed the `alert` function call to `console.log` and it is fine now.