# When the browser announces JavaScript codes time execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

Sometimes when I load my website, this message appears in the console:

[image]

Why is this shown? Aren't my JS code optimized enough? And what should I do now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Violation Long running JavaScript task took xx ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Answer (score 0):

`reflow` is the name of the web browser process for re-calculating the positions and geometries of elements in the document, for the purpose of re-rendering part or all of the document.

Your Browser stops the execution of the script because `reflow` is user-blocking

Take a look at this List of what operations force reflow: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a

Comment: Well what's that mean? Are my codes ok? Or should I do something particular?

Comment: Right. You should improve your code in a way that it does less DOM manipulation at one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all about it here.

[Violation Long running JavaScript task took xx ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms)

See the answers to get to know what it is and why the warning shows up.

To trace the cause, I would recommend you employ Binary search technique and keep dividing your java-script code and commenting them till you get to the line/lines which are causing this problem.