# Why do Chrome violations occur and how to fix them?

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, warnings

In my Dev console in Chrome, certain violations occur on nearly every site, big web portals, reddit, even stackoverflow.

t-online portal:

> [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 32ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 88ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 80ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 88ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 52ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 87ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 147ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 123ms

reddit:

> [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 289ms

stackoverflow:

> [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 42ms

Our very own ExtJS app:

> [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 1208ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 122ms
>   [Violation] 'readystatechange' handler took 344ms
>   [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 42ms

So, what are these Violations? Something took too long, but

- can I safely ignore these violations?
- how long may stuff take? 42ms seems not that much.
- how can I break down the things that have to be done into smaller chunks?
- how can this be done in existing frameworks, namely ExtJS? Is this doable for me as a developer, or do I have to wait for Sencha to do it for me?

Comment: This only happens when the developer tools console setting is set to log `Verbose`.

Comment: You can safely ignore these messages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms