# web pages suddenly not dsiplaying images or downloading scripts: 431 error

Tags: html, http, https

I find a 431 error for those pages when I search the debugger. They display fine on edge.

431 normally means headers are too big, I think. But the headers seem normal and no different to other pages.
Also it is not refusing to display the pages just the javascript and images embeded are not being downloaded. Chrome seems to begin the process and then when it comes to downloading images or a script, just throws the error and stops.
The error is confined not just to chrome, but also to https://   (secure pages.) and a certain folder called comms where mautic is installed and has been working well and not been changed or updated in any way.
http://xxxx.com/comms/media/images/c09f536bfb082c42312f45d989c4c0a0.png  displays
https://xxxx.com/comms/media/images/c09f536bfb082c42312f45d989c4c0a0.png  fails

The parent folder is secure and has always worked fine. I t should work for either secure or insecure versions as far as I understand. Always has done.
Most importantly it normally works and has suddenly stopped, yet nothing has been changed at my end.

Any suggestions about where to start looking?

**Chrome Warnings:**

```
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 90ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 91ms
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 
[Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 179ms 
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 115ms 
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 45ms
```

Comment: Yes: HTTP 431 means [Request Header Fields Too Large](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/431).  The problem lies with the web page making the request.  There is "something wrong" with the client.  One way to troubleshoot is to examine the offending client requests in Chrome Developer Tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: Thanks, that seems spot on.
I have now narrowed it to my laptop using chrome, not other machine or browser combination. In some ways that's a relief, but still I don't want the customer of your dreams with a identical laptop to see this.

I have freed a lot of memory but no luck so far. Ill let you know if I resolve it

Comment: [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 90ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 91ms
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 [Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 179ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 115ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 45ms

Im out of practice with Javascript and especialy the libraries and frameworks, does tis mean anything to anyone?

It reports 2 errors, but shows nothing when I click on them.

Comment: Good information - thank you.  Look here: [Violation Long running JavaScript task took xx ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/).  Frankly, this doesn't sound like code you wrote ... so I'm not sure there's much you're going to be able to do about it :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems the warning messages are a very different issue.
There also seems to be two problems rather than one.
The cause of the 431 problem was using - in a page name    e.g.  page-name.php
Only a problem on chrome and only on https , the http versions of the same pages worked fine.

I still have some pages loading without images or scripts. The issue seems to be around mixed content.
If download the http version it works, but the https version does not.
Given the struggling page is domain/subdirectory  and the domain has a valid certificate 
I assume subdirectory should also be working fine.