# How to change controllist in html using js?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

1.So I want to change `controlist="nodownload"` to `controlist="download"` 
          after the page loads using Javascript.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <audio id="preview"controls=" " controlist="nodownload" 
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
      </audio>
   </body>
</html>
```

2.my javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByid("preview"); 
  x.setAttribute("controlist", "download");
}
```

this doesn't work so can you rectify my errors to make it work.
   `[Violation] 'load' handler took 23639ms`
    `[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 73ms`
    `[Violation] 'visibilitychange' handler took 762ms`

Comment: You have mistake 'controlist' in html and 'controlslist' in JS

Answer (score 0):

change that:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByid("preview"); 
  x.setAttribute("controlslist", "download");
}
```

to:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementsByid("preview"); 
  x.setAttribute("controlist", "download");
}
```

You wrong to write `x.setAttribute("controlist", "download");`

example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("preview"); 
  x.setAttribute("controlist", "download");
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <audio id="preview"controls=" " controlist="nodownload" 
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
      </audio>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ` [Violation] 'load' handler took 23639ms`
    `[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 73ms`
    `[Violation] 'visibilitychange' handler took 762ms`

Comment: your js but dosen't  show  three vertical dots which allows  download option.but it works but dosen't change from no download to download

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms) for violation and you ask how to change controlist value and now js work.