# Angular nested *ngFor / render performance

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have run into a performance issue - I can not seem to solve.

Basically I have this dynamic table like structure that works like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let column of columnData">
    <div *ngFor="let rowItem of column.rowItems">
      <div [innerHTML]="getHtml(rowItem.info)"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in my component I have a function that takes the rowItem data and then returns some html markup like so

```
getHtml(data) {
  if (...) {
    return `
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    `
  } else if {
    return `
      <svg>
        ...
      </svg>
    `
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

now my data structure is as follows

```
columnData = [
  {
    columnHeader: 'test'
    rowItems: [
      {
         rowHeader: 'test',
         value: 1
      },
      // ...
    ]
  },
  // ...
]
```

so there may be 100 columns, and each `column` has 25 `rowItems` - now the `rowItems` are almost identical except for the value + some other values I havent displayed but for example the `rowHeader` always stays the same.

so for the layout to display correctly, we need to loop through each `column` and also loop through each `rowItem` - so this becomes a nested for loop. Now with a small amount of data this works fine - but we have quite a lot of data and some objects have 100 columns and 50 rows, so this slows the site down quite considerably - this is the performance

[image]

as you can see quite a lot of scripting, now when I remove the nested for loop I get the following

[image]

a considerable improvement, but obviously I still need to be able to generate the `rowItems.`

I have tried using a virtual list - but it is still quite laggy / buggy as it scrolls.

What generally happens is as im scrolling horizontally the whole screen will go white and ill get this warning in the browser

[image]

I have also tried progressive rendering, where I only render 10 columns at a time, but this still isnt very performant.

Is there anything else I can do?

Any help would be appreciated

As suggested I tried to implemenet trackBy like so

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let column of columnData; trackBy: columnTrackByFn">
    <!-- ... -->
    <div *ngFor="let rowItem of column.rowItems; trackBy: rowTrackByFn">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
columnTrackByFn(index, item) {
  return item.colId;
}

rowTrackByFn(index, item) {
  return item.rowId;
}
```

and it didnt help, if anything is made it slower

[image]

Comment: Have you tried trackBy: check this:https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Comment: @Chellappanவ I have updated my question, it didnt seem to help.. did I implement it correctly?

Comment: For this best solution is virtual scrolling, but as you said its laggy for you I think you should check your implementation again. Check https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-use-virtual-scrolling-using-angular-7-cdk-9802110111fa.

Comment: @vaibhavmaster my issue is that my virtual scroll, needs to scroll horizontally - and the cdk and ngx-virtual-for dont seem to support this very well - not only that for each rowItem i need to render some html so all of this really affects the performance of the virtual scroll

Comment: Post what you do inside your ngFor within the <!-- ... --> We have loops like these without any performance problems. The performance hit is in what you do within

Comment: @Max i have updated the question - within each rowItem loop it is calling a function that returns some html markup

Comment: Hi You have implemented trackBy correct only,  I am not sure why it's taking too long to paint, check this post it might help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms

Comment: @Chellappanவ my only thought is the rowId is not unique, for each column there will be a rowItem withe same ID, could this be causing any issues?

Comment: Could be. If row is not unique, can you try track with index?

Comment: @Chellappanவ using the index for the trackBy has definitely speed it up

Comment: @SmokeyDawson yeah, that `<div [innerHTML]="getHtml(rowItem.info)"></div>` is suspect too. Any way you could move the getHtml() into a normal data binding so you don't call a function?