# [Violation]'s for click, non-passive event listener, readystatechange, requestAnimationFrame and more

Tags: reactjs

I must have clicked something in chrome devtools, not sure what, but even since doing so we have been receiving [Violation] warnings we were not previously receiving.

- `[Violation] 'readystatechange' handler took 165ms`
- `[Violation] 'click' handler took 402ms`
- `[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 57ms`
- `[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952`

[image]

...to list a few. These warning are occurring locally in our React application, and tend to appear when toggling different buttons / widgets / pages of our application.

Are these warnings okay to keep, or should we try to fix the code that is generating these? I'm not even sure what code to share to showcase where these warnings are coming from, or how to create a reproducible example for this.

**Edit:** [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms) seems related but doesn't provide any recommendations for resolving the warnings.

Comment: To fix it you need to do less work on the main thread, that's what the warnings are about. The question you linked seems like a duplicate of this post in regards on how to show/hide the messages