# Blazor RichTextEditor not showing contents in Azure. Works in Localhost

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side, xaf

In my XAF 21.2.4 Entity Framework Blazor application (With the Office options)

There is a business object property notated as

```
    [EditorAlias(EditorAliases.RichTextPropertyEditor)]
    public string Info { get; set; }
```

The Rich text editor displays content correctly when I run the app in localhost.

But when I deploy to an Azure app (Windows) no content displays.

I notice a message in the Chrome browser tools

```
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 43ms
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218507/violation-long-running-javascript-task-took-xx-ms

Comment: Chrome is just saying that your code [is blocking the UI too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little late to the party. I had the same issue and solved it by turning on AzureCompatibility.

https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.Utils.AzureCompatibility.Enable